# replacing special chars by ASCII equivalent before writing to file

Tags: java

I am getting an java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException when trying to write a csv that contains the char **µ**.

I need to write the file with ASCII encoding so that Excel can open it directly without the user having to do anything.

How can I convert my **µ** char into its ASCII equivalent before writing to file ?

Comment: `µ` has no ascii equivalent. What do you expect in its place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII only takes the lower 7 bits of the character. So there are only 2^7 = 128 characters possible. However, of those only 95 are actually printable (read: visible), and that *includes* the space character (because it still has a fixed width). Unfortunately, your character is not part of that list.

The most used ASCII compatible character encoding is probably UTF-8 by now. However, that requires two bytes to create Mu / the micro-symbol (`0xC2 0xB5`).

Western Latin, also known as ISO/IEC 8859-1 (since 1987), has the character at U+00B5 (Alt+0181), translated as 0xB5 in hexadecimal notation. Western Latin is however not used that much as a name. Instead, the extended version called Windows-1252 is used, with the character at the same location.

You can see the Unicode encoding [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b5/index.htm) and the Windows-1252 [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b5/charset_support.htm) (at the fileformat.info site).

Comment: Thanks, that was very stupid of me. Excel did not understand the µ whenever I saved as UTF8, so I wrongly thought that I needed to save as ASCII. In fact, when I save as Windows1252, Excel is ok reading the µ sign.